# SQL Get Union Result into different cols

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

What is the best to way, to get a Union result into different cols

For example

```
SELECT 1 AS Col1
UNION
SELECT 2 AS Col2
```

Result:

```
| Col1 | Col2 |
|  1   |   2  |
```

The only way I see it, is to create a auxiliary table with two cols and insert each value in the respective col. However, I would like a cleaner and better way.

(There is no unique key between both selects, to make a JOIN)

Comment: `CROSS JOIN` don't `UNION`. Or, considering the simplicity, just do `SELECT 1 AS Col1, 2 AS Col2;`>

Comment: I didn't know I could do a `CROSS JOIN` without a Unique Key. Both solutions worked. Thanks